# Website API problem on casting the XML output

Tags: sql-server, sql, xml, casting

Hi guys as the title says, I'm using an API to get the weather information by country and city. Everything works great, the output is being returned. But when I try to cast the varchar to xml i get problems.

Look at my code and the output:

```
Declare @Object as Int;
Declare @ResponseText as Varchar(8000) ;
DECLARE @XML XML;

Exec sp_OACreate 'MSXML2.XMLHTTP', @Object OUT;
Exec sp_OAMethod @Object, 'open', NULL, 'get', 'http://www.webservicex.net/globalweather.asmx/GetWeather?CityName=Stockholm&CountryName=Sweden', 'false'
Exec sp_OAMethod @Object, 'send'
Exec sp_OAMethod @Object, 'responseText', @ResponseText OUTPUT 

select @ResponseText
set @xml = cast(@ResponseText as xml);
select @XML
```

Output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<string xmlns="http://www.webserviceX.NET">&lt;?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?&gt;
&lt;CurrentWeather&gt;
  &lt;Location&gt;Stockholm / Bromma, Sweden (ESSB) 59-21N 017-57E 14M&lt;/Location&gt;
  &lt;Time&gt;Nov 12, 2013 - 04:20 PM EST / 2013.11.12 2120 UTC&lt;/Time&gt;
  &lt;Wind&gt; from the SW (220 degrees) at 10 MPH (9 KT):0&lt;/Wind&gt;
  &lt;SkyConditions&gt; partly cloudy&lt;/SkyConditions&gt;
  &lt;Temperature&gt; 44 F (7 C)&lt;/Temperature&gt;
  &lt;DewPoint&gt; 41 F (5 C)&lt;/DewPoint&gt;
  &lt;RelativeHumidity&gt; 87%&lt;/RelativeHumidity&gt;
  &lt;Pressure&gt; 29.83 in. Hg (1010 hPa)&lt;/Pressure&gt;
  &lt;Status&gt;Success&lt;/Status&gt;
&lt;/CurrentWeather&gt;</string>
```

The casted:

```
<string xmlns="http://www.webserviceX.NET">&lt;?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?&gt;
&lt;CurrentWeather&gt;
  &lt;Location&gt;Stockholm / Bromma, Sweden (ESSB) 59-21N 017-57E 14M&lt;/Location&gt;
  &lt;Time&gt;Nov 12, 2013 - 04:20 PM EST / 2013.11.12 2120 UTC&lt;/Time&gt;
  &lt;Wind&gt; from the SW (220 degrees) at 10 MPH (9 KT):0&lt;/Wind&gt;
  &lt;SkyConditions&gt; partly cloudy&lt;/SkyConditions&gt;
  &lt;Temperature&gt; 44 F (7 C)&lt;/Temperature&gt;
  &lt;DewPoint&gt; 41 F (5 C)&lt;/DewPoint&gt;
  &lt;RelativeHumidity&gt; 87%&lt;/RelativeHumidity&gt;
  &lt;Pressure&gt; 29.83 in. Hg (1010 hPa)&lt;/Pressure&gt;
  &lt;Status&gt;Success&lt;/Status&gt;
&lt;/CurrentWeather&gt;</string>
```

First of all, ain't I able to return the: `&gt;s and &lt;s as < >` ? 
Secondy what i think is happinging here is that the `<?xml ..... ?>` is changing place and that ruins the xml.

And how may I convert the first output to valid XML?

**Edit:** I fixed this by adding:

```
set @ResponseText = replace(replace(replace(@ResponseText,'&gt;','>'),'&lt;','<'),'<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
','');
```

But I still wonder, is there a better approach?

Comment: i dont see how this belongs to SO, it's dba stuff! or isn't it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try the .value method of the xml datatype to de-entitize the xml, eg this worked for me:

```
DECLARE @Object AS INT;
DECLARE @ResponseText AS VARCHAR(8000) ;
DECLARE @XML XML;

EXEC sp_OACreate 'MSXML2.XMLHTTP', @Object OUT;
EXEC sp_OAMethod @Object, 'open', NULL, 'get', 'http://www.webservicex.net/globalweather.asmx/GetWeather?CityName=Stockholm&CountryName=Sweden', 'false'
EXEC sp_OAMethod @Object, 'send'
EXEC sp_OAMethod @Object, 'responseText', @ResponseText OUTPUT 

SELECT CAST( @ResponseText AS XML ).value('.', 'VARCHAR(MAX)') rt
SET @xml = CAST( @ResponseText AS XML ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
SELECT @xml
```